# Add N' Character Before Insert statement SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem that needing help, please give me an advice.
I want to insert database from one Oracle Server to SQL server by statements as:

```
SELECT * INTO ABC_temp SELECT * FROM DIM_PROVINCE
```

In DIM_PROVINCE and ABC_temp  have 3 columns: `PROVINCE_ID`, `PROVINCE_NAME` and `NOTE`
The problem is It can not shows VietNamese Language. After I searched on the internet for helping, everybody shows that I must use N’ character before INSERT statement.
So, how can I replace this statement.

```
INSERT INTO ABC_temp values (N’abc,N’abc,N’abc)
```

By statement bellows:

```
SELECT * INTO ABC_temp SELECT * FROM DIM_PROVINCE
```

Thank You!

Comment: What are your column types?  VARCHAR or NVARCHAR?

Comment: Please provide the schema for both of the tables.

Comment: PROVINCE_ID: INT
PROVINCE_NAME: NVARCHAR
NOTE: NVARCHAR

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to.

The `'N'` is used to denote that the string is a unicode literal, so if the datatype in Oracle is unicode as well, there may not be a need to convert (SQL Server does an implicit conversion from `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR`).

Otherwise, you can cast the values (see [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You put the N outside the single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO ABC_temp values (N'abc', N'abc', N'abc')
```

The SQL statement should follow the syntax:

```
insert into ABC_temp
select * from DIM_PROVINCE
```

(In SQL Server, this is how you do it.  I'm not sure about the syntax in Oracle.)